Ability to catch and resend DOM messages which are grid scoped
Is there a way to handle all slickgrid messages in a centralized way by catching and killing them, and upon a specific event (a async callback or a specified interval of time for example) resend them ?
Basically i need to capture a specific event, saving all event informations, then issue an async call to a server method, and after got the response re-create the same DOM or slickgrid event and send it to the grid as if it was the original one.
This of course can be done via DOM browser events but i like a more high-level, centralized and SlickGrid functionality.
Thx. in advance.
A centralized event handler and a mechanism to re-send a previously cached event.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
